# Create REST APIs to communicate CRM with Wordpress

Tags: ruby, wordpress, api

What should I ask my programmer to pull the properties that are in the CRM account to multiple wordpress installations.
It is possible using Ruby and creating a REST APIs, according to their site: https://ayuda.easybroker.com/article/330-api-de-easybroker-beta

Because you can't use JavaScript, TypeScript, React / React Native, Vue, Angular or similar. If you are going to use a programming language other than Ruby, you will need to create the interactions yourself. And it has to be on the back-end.

Does anyone know who can do it and how much does it cost?

Comment: Hello Trogloautoegocrata. Seems like you might want to have a look at this plugin as a baseline for understanding how to sync multiple installs or databases With the help of someone who understands databases and can configure the plugin it should work out for you.


  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-data-access/